# How do I select columns by name while ignoring certain characters?

Tags: r, regex, data.table, fread

I'm trying to pull data from a file, but only pull certain columns based on the column name.

I have this bit of code:

```
filepath <- ([my filepath])
files <- list.files(filepath, full.names=T)
newData <- fread(file,select=c(selectCols))
```

selectCols contains a list of column names (as strings). But in the data I'm pulling, there may be underscores placed differently in each file for the same data.

Here's an example:

```
PERIOD_ID
PERIOD_ID_
_PERIOD_ID_
```

And so on. I know I can use gsub to change the column names once the data is already pulled:

```
colnames(newData) <- gsub("_","",newData)
```

Then I can select by column name, but given that it's a lot of data I'm not sure this is the most efficient idea.

Is there a way to do ignore underscores or other characters within the fread function?

Comment: Fyi, there's a request that might cover this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2066

Comment: I assume the columns might be in different positions in the data, which is why you can't use position numbers instead of column names?

Comment: @brittenb the position numbers may not be consistent, so I cannot use those.

Comment: Might be best then to create a function that first runs `fread(file, nrows=0)` to get the column names, use `grep` to find the columns you want to select, and then run `fread(file, select=cols)` to read in the data.

Comment: I do not think regex is your friend here unless there is a very limited amount of column names on that list. The problem is that you would need to create a regex for each unique column name. So you may be able to find any version of `PERIOD_ID`, but you would need another regex expression for another unique col and the variants. You could create regex that pulls only the letter characters from the names, and then search that list, but you are already doing something similar with gsub.